# Request Filter Attribute not executing on ServiceStack

Tags: rest, filter, servicestack

I'm running ServiceStack version 4.x and I've created a custom Request Filter Attribute (it inherits from RequestFilterAttribute).

I have some class methods using this custom attribute with ApplyTo parameter. Whenever I use normal HTTP calls the filter gets executed perfectly, the problem comes when one of my services calls internaly a method from another service, the filter then is not executed.

According to the documentation that can be found here:

[Order of operations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations)

For non HTTP calls, Request filters with priority >= 0 will be executed right before Action filters.

I have no idea why this is not working, maybe is a bug on the implementation or I misunderstood the documentation.

Any idea how to solve this or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Note the [non-HTTP Global Request Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations#mq-non-http-custom-hooks) is linked to the [Messaging Global Request and Response Filters](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters#message-queue-endpoints) docs which refer to the MQ Request Filters, i.e:

```
appHost.GlobalMessageRequestFilters
appHost.GlobalMessageResponseFilters
```

Only the `appHost.PreRequestFilters` are executed everywhere, i.e. for every Raw HTTP Handler, HTTP or MQ Service, etc.

Comment: So there's absolutely no method attribute that will be called for every request (http and non http)?

Comment: @PizergSensing `appHost.PreRequestFilters` are executed on http/non http request. What do you mean by method attribute? FilterAttributes on methods should also get executed in both http/non-http contexts.

Comment: RequestFilterAttributes are not executed for non-http direct service calls

Comment: @PizergSensing they should be when they're attributed on the method itself.